# how can i use url parameter in controller using angular?

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I'm using angular 1.5.0-beta2

i want to be able to read the parameter `/cocktail/:cocktail_name`

here i define the app and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myalcoholist',['ngMaterial','ngRoute']);
app.controller('CocktailController',['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.cocktailStepsRows=null;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.myalcoholist.com:8888/cocktail/steps/' + $scope.cocktail_name
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.cocktailStepsRows=response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert('error');
        });

}]);
```

as you can see i'm trying to append to the api url `$scope.cocktail_name`

this is how i configure ng-view:

```
   app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController'
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/cocktail/:cocktail_name', {
            templateUrl: 'views/cocktail.html',
            controller: 'CocktailController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);
```

as you can see i configured the route properly to receive the cocktail_name parameter.

now the problem i'm having is that in the controller, `$scope.cocktail_name` is undefined.

in the view when i print cocktail name

```
{{cocktail_name}}
```

I receive the parameter properly. why not in the controller?
what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not copy the parameter value to the scope. Fix it using:

```
$scope.cocktail_name = $routeParams.cocktail_name
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10394426)

Comment: @GAMITG The author expected to have the URL parameter in the scope. But he did not copy the value to the scope. The statement I provided fixes the issue. BTW how can you review Angular related answer if you are not familiar with Angular at all?

Comment: hi! no need to argue! :) i injected $routeParams and used it. thanks for your answer.